# How to convert mono or stereo audio to spatial?

Tags: headphones

Can anyone teach me the way to convert mono or stereo tracks to spatial? I've been panning the audio to the back but it didn't seem to work efficiently. The sound was only able to move to the front, left and right. Any advice or teaching will be deeply appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I think this topic has been covered in various questions here already - have a search for spatial stereo or wide stereo - I think you'll find a few posts on it.

Comment: May I know why by panning audio to the back in 5.1 channels, the sound loses a bit and feels like it's stayed at the centre but softer.

Comment: Because spatial audio is not just a case of panning. You need to be aware of phase shifts and delay. This is covered in other posts here, so have a good look around.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Your teaching will be deeply appreciated by me!